# How to sync NSUserDefaults into a twitter message?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, twitter, nsuserdefaults

Is there a way I can sync `NSUserDefaults` data inside `Twitter` message?

```
     if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {

        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

        SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
            if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {

                NSLog(@"Cancelled");

            } else

            {
                NSLog(@"Done");
            }

            [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
        };
        controller.completionHandler =myBlock;

        [controller setInitialText:@""];
        [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
        [controller addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];

        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];

    }
```

I need the set initial text to accept a nsuserdefaults, because I have some pretext setup by a user. Here is the nsuserdefaults.

```
 NSString *savestring =field.text;
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:savestring forKey:@"savedstring"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: hello @moo this fullfills your requirement or you want anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 [controller setInitialText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"savedstring"]];
```

And if you want string value if returning dictionary from user Defaults then you can use JSON to convert it to string.